# How can I return variables in controller and custom page using JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel

How can I return variables using `JSON` in controller and in the same time to return in custom page?
I want to implement this code

```
 Response::json(array(
'food' => $food,
'diou' => $DIOU,));
 return view('showbalance',['chart'=>$chart]);
```

Laravel: return response json and redirect to view page

Answer (score 1):

```
$response_variables  = array(
'food' => $food,
'diou' => $DIOU,);

//If needed : $response_variables = json_encode($response_variables);

return view('showbalance',compact('chart', 'response_variables'));
```

Then you can use your `$response_variables` in your view

Comment: I was about to write something like this. If you'd then really like your array to be in JSON-format, then you can (perhaps in your view), use this to encode your array to JSON-format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: not working, I want to show the chart and the two variables in the page showbalance

Comment: Using blade I assume. In your view `{{$response_variable->food}}` will display your food value. In this case you do not use `json_encode()`

Comment: I think you didnt get what I mean, your solution doesnt work with me

Answer (score 0):

There could be only one case, either you can return the data or you can load it on the page using only one function.

If you return the data first he controller's function will exit over there and won't execut the next line, so the page will not be loaded.

And in case if you load the page first the controller's function will not execute the next line.

Please do let me know if you are using same function for the API and WEB call.